# What are some quantum mechanics experiments that can be done with household items?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, home-experiment

I am interested in witnessing principals of quantum mechanics (Superposition, Quantum entanglement, Quantum tunneling, etc.) with simple household items.

The experiments that I have already tried are:

- The double slit experiment (by shining a laser through a double slit to make an interference pattern)
- Changing the color of fire by varying temperature and elements being burned
- Used two pairs of polarized sunglasses to alter to amount of light that passes through by rotating the lenses

Are there any other interesting ones that I could try?

Comment: Since you don't have the equipment to send photons one by one, your first and third experiments do not probe QM: they are perfectly modelled by classical electromagnetism.

Comment: Any LED or flourescent works because of QM.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure molar heat capacity of graphite at room temperature, it is [much lower](http://ch301.cm.utexas.edu/data/section2.php?target=heat-capacities.php) than that predicted by the classical equipartition theorem (Dulong-Petit law) due to quantum effects. Graphite is [cheap](https://www.walmart.com/ip/99-9-High-Purity-Graphite-Ingot-Block-for-Smooth-Surface-2X2X0-79-Black/286680985?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=18528&adid=22222222227160978494&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=272288140799&wl4=pla-450862792776&wl5=9027637&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=125216233&wl11=online&wl12=286680985&wl13=&veh=sem&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIk8iQqo3B4AIVCB6tBh1xFwb7EAQYAyABEgK9SPD_BwE), [measurement of heat capacity](https://fizipedia.bme.hu/images/4/4c/Calorimetry.pdf) does not seem too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you did already many tunneling experiments at home - like many other people. Mechanical electric switches have layers of sulfides, oxides and other non-conducting material at their 2 contact zones. But still the resistor is very low, i.e. the lamp is working with normal intensity if the switch is closed. Many switches are constructed to scratch a little bit in order to break through these multi-atomic layers, but often both sides of the contact do not touch directly and are still separated by  non-conducting layers in state switched on. F.e. gold has an oxide layer, but this layer is limited to only a few atoms of thickness. So in order to work, mechanical switches need electrons to tunnel through non-conducting layers - and have also to tunnel at the surface barrier of the metal - nonmetal contact zones. So simply switching electric circuits is a common household tunnel experiment, that only fails if the corrosion/layers of the contact zones have become too thick.